# Docker. Tomcat7 don't run

Tags: docker, tomcat7

I'm trying to run Tomcat 7 on Docker. 
`team sudo Docker pull kotyara:7.0.62-jre8` is going well. The download is successful.

After I try to run the image with some parameters, the command looks like this:

```
sudo Docker run -D -P -In /storage/data/kotyar/web applications:/usr/local/kotyar/web applications -In /storage/data/kotyar/logs:/usr/local/kotyar/logs-kotyar name:7.0.62-jre8 . Then I get the following error:
```

Response to error from daemon:

> lstat/storage/docker/overlay 2 / 6dd8ad08f0702d88f545c6fad62b58f74c95dc5e234fe7668536407019bcebbd: no such file or directory. See. section "docker run --help"

I also tried to just run the image without any parameters and still get the same error. An example of the image run:

```
sudo Docker run-name Tomcat Tomcat:7.0.62-jre8
```

How can I get rid of this problem? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [moby/moby issue 11012](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/11012#issuecomment-393097195):

> If you are running overlay or overlay2 on top of XFS, make sure you don't see this warning in the output of `docker info`:
>
> ```
> The backing xfs filesystem is formatted without `d_type` support, which leads to incorrect behavior.
> ```
>
> Reformat the filesystem with `ftype=1` to enable `d_type` support.
>
> You can also check the Supports `d_type` field in the storage-driver section in the output of `docker info`:
>
> ```
> Storage Driver: overlay
>  Backing Filesystem: xfs
>  Supports d_type: false
> ```
>
> If you do see that warning, the problem may be related to that.
>
> Running overlay (or overlay2) on XFS without `d_type` is known to cause issues.
>   Docker currently "allows" it for backward-compatibility on existing installations, but will not use the overlay/overlay2 driver on fresh installations.
>
> Also see these issues, which contain some information [#10294](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/10294), [#29873](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/29873).
>
> The RHEL release notes mentions this: "[File Systems / OverlayFS](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/7.2_Release_Notes/technology-preview-file_systems.html)":
>
> > Note that XFS file systems must be created with the `-n ftype=1` option enabled for use as an overlay.
> >     With the `rootfs` and any file systems created during system installation, set the `--mkfsoptions=-n ftype=1` parameters in the Anaconda kickstart.
> >     When creating a new file system after the installation, run the `# mkfs -t xfs -n ftype=1 /PATH/TO/DEVICE` command.
> >     To determine whether an existing file system is eligible for use as an overlay, run the `# xfs_info /PATH/TO/DEVICE | grep ftype` command to see if the `ftype=1` option is enabled.

So, first, double-check `docker info` output: your question depends on your OS and docker version.